Why are there Zhaitan heads on top of The Wizard's Tower?
On top of The Wizard's Tower you can find this (looks like Zhaitan heads).

Can't really interact with it. Any idea why it is there?

There's no explanation lore-wise for it (at least not for now). It seems to be more like an easter egg.
Aside from the Zaithan one you've pointed out, it hosts many other ones, such as one about Halloween, Wintersday, Karka, bunnies, and even cats.
